# how to prove this curious identity with the Chebyshev polinomials

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials

we defined the Tm like this (where Tm are the Chebyshev polinomials)

[image]

Then I showed this:

[image]

And now I have no idea how to proove this:

[image]

I also have to make the remark that I also proved that the characteristic function of this matrix corresponds to the normed Chebyshev polinomials

[image]

It would very nice, if somebody could give me a hint. I tried induction but it didn't worked because the (m+1)-st Chebyshev polinomial has not the same roots as the m-th Chebyshev polinomial.

Comment: What definition are you using for the Chebyshev polynomials? The trigonometric definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) gives the answer almost immediately. And what do you mean when you say you "showed" that $\xi_\nu = \cos(\pi(2\nu-1)/2m)$? It looks like a definition of $\xi_\nu$.

Comment: I don't see, how this could follow immediately from the trigonometric definition. Could you give me perhaps a hint?

Comment: The trig definition is equivalent to $T_n(\cos\theta) = \cos(n\theta)$. It's easy to find the $n$ values of $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$ that make the right-hand side equal to $0$; so now you know the roots of $T_n$....